# Android Resolve Host

Tags: android, web-services

I am getting the following error while trying to access the web-service.

`Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "192.168.1.109"`

Web-service is working fine, when checked using browser.

I am using AsyncTask to access web-service, so it cannot be a background thread issue.

Missed this permission:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

as identified in the answer below.

Comment: You'll have to include the code where you're doing this access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly I doubt it has to do with the permission you need to give while running the app. Are you making sure you are setting the the network permission in manifest?

More information or code could help you get better answers though.

Comment: Oops, and you are absolutely right, i forget to add the permission. TY